# How to fix this problem when importing matplotlib

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have been trying to import matplotlib in Python3 when facing this problem.

```
>>> import matplotlib
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 123, in <module>
    from . import cbook
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/matplotlib/cbook/__init__.py", line 36, in <module>
    import numpy as np
  File "/home/bob/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 142, in <module>
    from . import core
  File "/home/bob/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py", line 59, in <module>
    from . import numeric
  File "/home/bob/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/numeric.py", line 3093, in <module>
    from . import fromnumeric
  File "/home/bob/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py", line 17, in <module>
    from . import _methods
  File "/home/bob/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/_methods.py", line 158, in <module>
    _NDARRAY_ARRAY_FUNCTION = mu.ndarray.__array_function__

***AttributeError: type object 'numpy.ndarray' has no attribute '__array_function__'***
```

Comment: How did you install `matplotlib` package?

Comment: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/12736

Answer (score 0):

Try by using the following code

```
import matplotlib as plt
% matpllotlib inline
```

Comment: I found out that it actually stems from the repetition of numpy !!!Thanks a lot for helping me !!!

Comment: Well no problem and good luck for your code